# change list box dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, machine-learning, flask

I got a index.html file where multiple option is used within select tag for a drop down:

```
 <label for="edu">Education</label>
 <select id="edu" name="edu">
  <option value="0">10th</option>
  <option value="1">11th</option>
  <option value="2">12th</option>
  <option value="3">1st-4th</option>
  <option value="4">5th-6th</option>
  <option value="5">7th-8th</option>
  <option value="6">9th</option>
  <option value="7">Assoc-acdm</option>
  <option value="8">Assoc-voc</option>
  <option value="9">Bachelors</option>
  <option value="10">Doctorate</option>
  <option value="11">HS-grad</option>
  <option value="12">Masters</option>
  <option value="13">Preschool</option>
  <option value="14">Prof-school</option>
  <option value="15">16 - Some-college</option>
  </select>
```

This entire select tag is within a form element, basically to create a webapp for machine learning model using flask framework.

Is there a way using javascript, where I can generate this option values and list box dynamically in html,

> also, need the same option values between 0 to 15 to be assigned since that would the input to the prediction model

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the contents in an array, iterate, and set the value of the option to the index:

```js
const values = [
  "10th",
  "11th",
  "12th",
  "1st-4th",
  "5th-6th",
  "7th-8th",
  "9th",
  "Assoc-acdm",
  "Assoc-voc",
  "Bachelors",
  "Doctorate",
  "HS-grad",
  "Masters",
  "Preschool",
  "Prof-school",
  "16 - Some-college"
];
values.forEach((e,i) => edu.innerHTML += `<option value=${i}>${e}</option>`);
```

```html
<label for="edu">Education</label>
<select id="edu" name="edu"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Spectric, could you please help me with adding the const values part into the html code, should it be added to script tag?? thanks as I'm relatively new to Javascript

Comment: @omdurg What "const values part"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two ways.

1. Using `innerHTML`.
2. Using DOM API directly to create things.

Using `innerHTML`

```js
// List of options
const list = ["12th", "11th", "10th"];

// Grabbing the select element from DOM
const selectField = document.getElementById("edu"); // `edu` is the id of select element in html

// DOM string which is about get generated and inserted.
let optionsString = "";

// Generating the string
list.forEach((item, index) => {
  optionsString += ` <option value="${index}">${item}</option>`
});

// Inserting the string
selectField.innerHTML = optionsString;
```

```html
 <label for="edu">Education</label>
 <select id="edu" name="edu">

  </select>
```

Using DOM API

```
// List of options
const list = ["12th", "11th", "10th"];

// Grabbing the select element from DOM
const selectField = document.getElementById("edu"); // `edu` is the id of select element in html

// Creating and attaching elements on the fly.
list.forEach((item, index) => {
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = index;
  option.innerText = item;
  selectField.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
 <label for="edu">Education</label>
 <select id="edu" name="edu">

  </select>
```

Comment: Thanks @DJ Hemath, could you please help me with adding the const values part into the html code, should it be added to script tag?? thanks as I'm relatively new to Javascript

Comment: If this is flask why not pass the required options and then use a for loop to add them to the select?

Comment: Yes it should be added inside `<script></script>`. And this script tags should be placed after your (or) as the last line in `<body>` tag.

Comment: Thank you @DJHemath, also is there a limit to generate this const list?

Comment: Nope, there is no limit for it.

Comment: Thanks @DJHemath, tried adding my list with 2000 unique values, but doesn't displays the drop down, also there's no error, so when I try to reduce the number of values in list, then it works